# Swift Compiler Error: 'Files.h' file not found

Tags: c, swift, xcode, module-map

I've got an Xcode project with the following file structure:

```
MyPlugin.xcodeproject
    sdk.xcconfig
    MyPlugin.c
    MyPlugin.swift
    MyPlugin-Bridging-Header.h
```

If I remove MyPlugin.swift from the target, everything compiles fine. Adding it to the target outputs the following error:

> Swift Compiler Error: 'Files.h' file not found

The contents of `MyPlugin-Bridging-Header.h` is simply:

```
#include "sdk.h"
```

That `sdk.h` is being found correctly in the search paths, however it has the following line which is where the error is occurring.

```
#include <Files.h>
```

Everything I've searched for has mentioned creating a `module.modulemap` file so I've have tried that with the following, but it doesn't fix the error:

```
module Files [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Files.h"
    export *
}
```

I'm currently wondering whether this modulemap will work if the `#include` statement I'm trying to fix is within the sdk.h rather than directly in the bridging header?

Additional set up info:

> Xcode 10, Swift 4.2, Deployment target: 10.9, Architectures: x86_64

Comment: Are you creating an executable or a framework with this project? Frameworks don't support ObjC bridging headers is why I ask.

Comment: Neither, it’s compiling to a Loadable Bundle (or Plug-in, not sure official terminology). Where would I look to check if they support bridging headers @bscothern ?

Comment: I haven't ever created one of those. Sadly the documentation over [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift) is lacking anything beyond using it in "apps" and "frameworks". Have you set the modulemap path in your xcconfig/xcodeproject? I'll dig into Loadable Bundles a bit and see if I can learn anything to help. (Sorry stack overflow comments are a pain to format sometimes...)

Comment: I've set it in the xcodeproject, not the xcconfig. Just tried it in the xccondig (via a copy and paste from the xcodeproject and it didn't seem to help, but I've never used one of those before. I could upload the project to GitHub if that helps, although not very StackOverflow style doing that?

Comment: If you are able to upload it somewhere I am happy to spend some more time looking at it to see if I can help you figure it out.

Comment: That would be amazing @bscothern thanks 
I've forked the SDK on GitHub and added my changes to one of the examples here: https://github.com/pixlwave/max-sdk/tree/master/source/basics/simplemax